# Toggle CSS property on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I am currently trying to add a CSS property to a div when the user has scrolled a certain distance down the page.

```
<div id="navbar">...</div>
```

```css
#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 1px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background: #009688;
}
```

I want to add `box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px #888888;` property to the CSS for #navbar, when the user has scrolled 209px down the page. I have tried to put this together already with jQuery I found online, but as I have next to no experience with jQuery, I couldn't make it work.

```
$("#navbar").css("box-shadow", "0px 3px 2px #888888");
```

And:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $('#navbar').toggle($(this).scrollTop()>209)
 });​
```

I hope I've made sense. Thank in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another class in your CSS and toggle it using javascript.

CSS:

`.navbar-scrolled {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px #888888;
}`

Javascript:

`$(document).scroll(function() {
  $("#navbar").toggleClass("navbar-scrolled", $(document).scrollTop() >= 209);
});`

Snippet below:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  $("#navbar").toggleClass("navbar-scrolled", $(document).scrollTop() >= 209);
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: #009688;
}
.navbar-scrolled {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px #888888;
}
#page-filler {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">navbar</div>
<div id="page-filler"></div>
```